# Read file metadata along with data in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, aes, metadata

I am using Python 3.7 along with a library for AES CBC on Windows 10 to encrypt files and it works perfectly. Except, after decrypting them, they lose their metadata like the date they were created. Because I want the user to feel like they never 'deleted' or 'lost' the original file, I need to preserve that data.

This is what I'm doing to read the data:

```
f = open(file_name, "rb")
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

After I encrypt the data, I write the encrypted bytes into a new file. When I decrypt this new file, I would like the metadata to be preserved so that the file (like an image) is exactly like it was before encryption. (P.S. I don't know if this will help but overwriting the new data on the original file might help but I want to try and avoid this if possible)

How do I include metadata of the file in a variable WITH the data that I am encrypting, such that when I decrypt, I get the exact same file with the same date created etc.?

EDIT:
I found a way to get the file creation time but I STILL NEED to get all the metadata as the file can be in any format: for example an image or a video, or a doc file's author. I also want to store this in the decrypted file which I don't know how to.

```
os.path.getctime(file_name)
```

Comment: Could you collect the metadata and store it in a second encrypted file?

Comment: @2br-2b if there is no possible way to include it in the same file, then yes. A second file for metadata is possible. What I don't understand is how you would put the metadata and the data together after decryption to save the original file. That's why I was trying to get it into one file such that when decrypted, the bytes are just the original file.